# ChartJs multiaxis chart show different label bottom and top

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using chart.js in order to render charts. I am using a multiaxis chart with a y-axis from -100 to 100 and a x-axis on the bottom with labels like black/white if the value > 0 it means black and if value<0 it means white.

I would like to separate the labels puting "black" on top and "white" at the bottom of the chart, how can I do it ?

```
var other = new Chart(ctx5,{
        type: 'radar',
        data: {
              labels:other_data_label,
              datasets:[{
                      data: behaviour_fixed_array, //processing_information_data,
                      backgroundColor: 'rgba(102, 187, 158,0.2)',
                      borderColor: 'rgb(102,187,158)',
                      pointBackgroundColor:'rgb(67, 122, 103)',
                        },
                        {
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(188,101,47,0.2)',
                        borderColor: 'rgb(168,101,47)',
                        pointBackgroundColor:'rgb(155, 21, 6)',
                        data: []
                        }]
              },
        options: {
              legend: {
                  position: 'top',
                  display: false
              },
              scale: {
                    display: true,
                    ticks: {
                          beginAtZero: true,
                            }
                     },
              responsive:true,
              maintainAspectRatio: true,
                 }
          });
     //end graph 5//
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do two things:
1. assign an xAxis to each data set
2. set different options for the xAxes inside of the options object

I started an example here -- note the xAxesID and scales array

```
data: {
  labels:other_data_label,
  datasets:[{
              data: behaviour_fixed_array, //processing_information_data,
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(102, 187, 158,0.2)',
              borderColor: 'rgb(102,187,158)',
              pointBackgroundColor:'rgb(67, 122, 103)',
              xAxisID: 'x-axis-1'
            },
            {
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(188,101,47,0.2)',
              borderColor: 'rgb(168,101,47)',
              pointBackgroundColor:'rgb(155, 21, 6)',
              data: [],
              xAxisID: 'x-axis-2'
            }]
          },
          options: {
            legend: {
              position: 'top',
              display: false
            },
            scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                display: true,
                position: 'top',
                id: 'x-axis-1'
              },
              {
                display: true,
                position: 'bottom',
                id: 'x-axis-2'
              }]
            },
            responsive:true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
          }
        });
```

Comment: Simplyy the bestt ;))) Thx you Katherine really helped ;)

Comment: I tried but I get twice the same labels, other_data_label how can I make them different please ?

Comment: because it works if it is numbers it will auto generate a scale but I would need string labels such as "black", "white"